# QStack (Android Mobile App)

Tags: app, android

[image]

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Insert a reasonably sized screenshot (or code snippet) of your
app here, so we can get a quick look at it and
an idea of how it works and what it might do for us.
[image]

App ScreenShot

### About

A Small personal app that displays questions and answers from StackOverflow with the ability to search users, see questions that have a set of tags and see all questions on StackOverflow API.
This app is my personal project, one I made because I can't seem to get a job so I decided to do something with my skills, I figured in my spare time, I can see questions and give answers to the one I know without launching StackOverflow from my web browser.

#### License

It's a completely free app. I will be happy if anyone can throw in an idea here and there of how I can improve the app.

#### Download

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alabian.android.qstack

#### Platform

It's an android mobile app.

### Contact

The app was solely created by me. You can reach me at chamellion555@gmail.com.

### Code

This app was written in kotlin. I will be happy if an android expert can do a quick code review for me(of course free). Am always looking to improve.
Code is on GitHub at: https://github.com/chamellion/QStacks

Comment: Do know we have a [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where you can ask for a review of a specific piece of code / style / implementation. So you can't drop a link to a whole project and get it reviewed but you can get feedback on a small part of it that you feel needs extra eyes. The feedback you get on the smaller bit might help improving the rest.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the code review stack exchange, I will make good use of it now. Gracias...